# ionic run android error: Could not find an installed version of gradle either in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-gradle-plugin

I got this error when i run ionic run android in my ionic 3 app console.
I saw many posts of it in stack over flow but nothing solve my issue.

```
 ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_101

Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue with cordova app (not ionic 3). I uninstalled sdk android and I installed Android Studio and now it works.